# MS MPI does not have the folder of includes

Tags: c++, windows, include, mpi, lib

I have downloaded the latest version of MPI from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=100593) version 10.1.2 on my windows 10. I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ol5L0IHXiOE) to install it. But, for mine, there is no folder of lib and includes when I want to modify the properties of my project. Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you install the SDK or only the runtime? They come as two separate installers.

Comment: @HristoIliev yes, It was two files named "msmpisetup.exe" and"msmpisdk.msi". I first ran .exe and then install .msi. But, the folder of Micrsoft MPI created does not have either libs or indludes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after installations, two folders will be created!
one is in program files named "Microsoft MPI" and the other one will be in programfiles(x86) named "Microsoft SDKs" which include both "includes" and "lib"